# By clicking on button doesn't make the insertion into data base?

Tags: java, swing, postgresql, user-interface, insert-into

I am having problems inserting data into a postgres table created using java. The created table part of the code works fine, its only when I am inserting values into the table that nothing happens. The code I am using to populate the table records is:

```
 //the first class code
         stmt = c.createStatement();    
     JavaApplication8 dc = new JavaApplication8();
            String sql = "INSERT INTO records (start_date,hour,cell_name,Erlang,ErlangU,cell_type,freq_type) VALUES ( ?,?,?,?,?,?,? )";
        PreparedStatement pst =  c.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setInt(1, dc.time());
             pst.setInt(2,heure );
             pst.setString(3, "fgf");
             pst.setFloat(4, 84/10);
             pst.setFloat(5,dc.Hourly_Traffic_900 );
             pst.setInt(6, 1);
             pst.setInt(7, 900);

      stmt.execute(sql);
        stmt.close();
             c.commit();
             c.close();
                  }} catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
             System.err.println( e.getClass().getName()+": "+ e.getMessage() );
             System.exit(0);
          }
          System.out.println("Records created successfully");}

//the jframe code 
         Connection conn = new DBConnection().Connect();
        private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try {

           float bsc = Float.parseFloat(jTextField1.getText());
            float cellsbsc = Float.parseFloat(jTextField2.getText());        
              float days = Float.parseFloat(jTextField3.getText());
         int tot_dense =(int) (bsc*cellsbsc) ;
          JavaApplication8 dc = new JavaApplication8();
           Menu mm = new Menu();
                    Connection c = null;
          Statement stmt = null;

             Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
             c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Records", "postgres", "21262050");
             c.setAutoCommit(false);
             System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

       String sql = "INSERT INTO records (start_date,hour,cell_name,Erlang,ErlangU,cell_type,freq_type) VALUES ( ?,?,?,?,?,?,? )";
             PreparedStatement pst =  c.prepareStatement(sql);
              if (mm.jRadioButton1.isSelected()&& mm.jButton1.isSelected()){

                   for(int i=1; i<tot_dense+1; i++)
                   {
                       for(int d=1; d<days+1; d++)

                       {
                           dc.Day_900();

             pst.setInt(1,dc.time() );
             pst.setInt(2,dc.heure );
             pst.setString(3, "fgf");
             pst.setFloat(4, 84/10);
             pst.setFloat(5,dc.Hourly_Traffic_900);
             pst.setInt(6, 1);
             pst.setInt(7, 900);

             pst.execute();
                       }
                   }
```

Comment: 1) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: This line `JavaApplication8 dc = new JavaApplication8();` appears twice even in the uncompilable code snippet above. I suspect that is the root of the problem. To trade suspicions for reasoned advice, post that MCVE.

Comment: There's a difference between `stmt` and `pst`, also try executing `pst.executeUpdate` instead

Answer (score 1):

So a few things stand out immediately:

1. You call `Connection#setAutoCommit` and set it to `false`, but never call `Connection#commit`
2. Generally, you should be calling `PreparedStatement#executeUpdate` instead of `execute`. It shouldn't make a significant difference, but `executeUpdate` actually returns the number of rows which were affected by the called, which can be helpful in diagnosing issues.
3. There's no indication in your code that you're actually closing any of your resources
4. You're calling `execute` in a loop, this tends to suggest a possible use for a batch update

So instead, you could do something like...

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    float bsc = Float.parseFloat(jTextField1.getText());
    float cellsbsc = Float.parseFloat(jTextField2.getText());
    float days = Float.parseFloat(jTextField3.getText());
    int tot_dense = (int) (bsc * cellsbsc);
    JavaApplication8 dc = new JavaApplication8();
    Menu mm = new Menu();

    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        try (Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Records", "postgres", "21262050")) {
            c.setAutoCommit(false);
            System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

            String sql = "INSERT INTO records (start_date,hour,cell_name,Erlang,ErlangU,cell_type,freq_type) VALUES ( ?,?,?,?,?,?,? )";
            try (PreparedStatement pst = c.prepareStatement(sql)) {
                if (mm.jRadioButton1.isSelected() && mm.jButton1.isSelected()) {

                    for (int i = 1; i < tot_dense + 1; i++) {
                        for (int d = 1; d < days + 1; d++) {
                            dc.Day_900();

                            pst.setInt(1, dc.time());
                            pst.setInt(2, dc.heure);
                            pst.setString(3, "fgf");
                            pst.setFloat(4, 84 / 10);
                            pst.setFloat(5, dc.Hourly_Traffic_900);
                            pst.setInt(6, 1);
                            pst.setInt(7, 900);

                            pst.addBatch();
                        }
                    }
                    pst.executeLargeBatch();
                    //pst.executeBatch();
                    c.commit();
                }

            }
        } catch (SQLException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();Ï
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Have a look at [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for some more details.

Having said all that, the next thing that jumps out is...

```
JavaApplication8 dc = new JavaApplication8();
Menu mm = new Menu();
```

You're using `mm` to check the state of some radio buttons, so, unless `Menu` is a modal dialog of some kind OR the radio buttons default selected state is set to `true`, it's unlikely that the update code will ever be executed

But, it doesn't stop there, having a look at the first code snippet raises some additional questions...

```
try {
    stmt = c.createStatement();
    JavaApplication8 dc = new JavaApplication8();
    String sql = "INSERT INTO records (start_date,hour,cell_name,Erlang,ErlangU,cell_type,freq_type) VALUES ( ?,?,?,?,?,?,? )";
    PreparedStatement pst = c.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.setInt(1, dc.time());
    pst.setInt(2, heure);
    pst.setString(3, "fgf");
    pst.setFloat(4, 84 / 10);
    pst.setFloat(5, dc.Hourly_Traffic_900);
    pst.setInt(6, 1);
    pst.setInt(7, 900);

    stmt.execute(sql);
    stmt.close();
    c.commit();
    c.close();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
    System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
    System.exit(0);
}
```

I don't know what `JavaApplication8` is, but it worries me, as you're relying on information from that class.

You use both a `Statement` and a `PreparedStatement`, but you `execute` only the `Statement` which makes no sense as the query is setup for a `PreparedStatement`, so that's just a mess of confusion.

You're also only closing the resources if everything actually succeeds, what happens if the query fails with a `SQLException`?  Those resources remain open!  See [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for a better solution

So, instead, the code "might" look like something more like...

```
try (Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Records", "postgres", "21262050")) {
    JavaApplication8 dc = new JavaApplication8();
    String sql = "INSERT INTO records (start_date,hour,cell_name,Erlang,ErlangU,cell_type,freq_type) VALUES ( ?,?,?,?,?,?,? )";
    try (PreparedStatement pst = c.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        pst.setInt(1, dc.time());
        pst.setInt(2, heure);
        pst.setString(3, "fgf");
        pst.setFloat(4, 84 / 10);
        pst.setFloat(5, dc.Hourly_Traffic_900);
        pst.setInt(6, 1);
        pst.setInt(7, 900);
        pst.executeUpdate();
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
    System.exit(0);
}
System.out.println("Records created successfully");
```

for example